# How to Transfer a property from Assertions Script to Test Case level in soapUI

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have written script in Assertions Script of one Test Step of REST API. I am able to get the property from Test Case level using context.testCase.getPropertyValue("id")

But I want also to transfer or set the property value from Script Assertions to Test Case level or Test Suite Level and that I am unable to do so.

Can you please suggest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that the correct place to set property values it's an assertion of **script assertion** type, however you can do it in that place using:

To create property at testCase level:

```
context.testCase.setPropertyValue("myProperty","myValue")
```

To create property at testSuite level:

```
context.testCase.testSuite.setPropertyValue("myProperty","myValues")
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: No, you can not set the property to test case level from script Assertion using setPropertyValue

Comment: @Himanshu I'm totally sure that it's possible, however as I told you probably it's not the place to do it...